# Configure `htaccess` to open contained `index` file when navigating to an existing directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'd like the following three rules in my site's `htaccess` file, but only the last two are working.

In writing rule one below, I've tried a number of codes, combinations, and orders, cobbled from postings elsewhere (taking care to commenting the other rules in testing). All I've gotten for it are 500, 404, and 403 errors.

Any help as to how to accomplish this, please?

```
#
# RULE ONE (FAIL)
# Navigation to a directory will open its contained 'index' file.
# This is so I can give visitors `mysite.com/project`, 
# rather having to give them `mysite.com/project/index.html`.
# 

#
# RULE TWO (GOOD)
# Navigation to a non-existent directory will redirect to a file
# of the same name and location.
# This is so if a visitor mistakenly goes to `mysite.com/somepage/`,
# they'll get to `mysite.com/somepage.html`.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#
# RULE THREE (GOOD)
# Navigation to a file without an extension will append an '.html' extension.
# This is so I can give a visitor `mysite.com/somepage`, 
# rather than `mysite.com/somepage.html`. 
# 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting redirect loops because apache will **always** redirect the browser to the URL that ends with a trailing slash when the request is for a directory. This is **very important** because it prevents the contents of the directory from being listed even if you have an index file (e.g. `index.html`). The [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive's documentation says:

> **Security Warning**
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where `mod_autoindex` is active (`Options +Indexe`s) and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, `index.htm`l) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the `index.html` file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents**.

That means, if you want to be able to go to directories without the trailing slash, you need to turn off `DirectorySlash`, and that means people will be able to see the contents of your directories (or get a 403 if you have `Indexes` turned off). So the only way around this is to do what `DirectorySlash` does except using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

---

edit: you've got other issues with your existing rules, try:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: @janaspage Sorry, I forgot to mention you need to turn off directory slash: `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: @janaspage also, you're old rules already conflict with each other, if you want to go to a folder, you're appending an `.html` to it, so it won't work. See edit, [those rules work for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CxG1j.png)

Comment: @janaspage maybe something else is wrong, as you can see in my image, they all work perfectly fine for me